# Missing value error when estimating nonlinear least square

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I'm trying to estimate the following CES production function -- 
$\log y=\log\gamma-\frac{\nu}{\rho}\log\left(\delta K^{-\rho}+\left(1-\delta\right)L^{-\rho}\right)+\epsilon$

So I use the following R code --

```
Data <- read.csv("Table.csv")
logy <- log(Data$Q)
K <- Data$COST*Data$SK/Data$PK
L <- Data$COST*Data$SL/Data$PL
Nls <- nls(logy~log(gamma)+(phi/rho)*log(delta*K^(-rho)+(1-delta)*L^(-rho)), data=Data, start=c(gamma=0.5, delta=0.5, rho=0.25, phi=1))
print(Nls)
```

with the data in `Table.csv`:

```
id,YEAR,COST,Q,PL,SL,PK,SK,PF,SF
1,1970,0.213,8,6869.47,0.3291,64.945,0.4197,18,0.2512
4,1970,3.0427,869,8372.96,0.103,68.227,0.2913,21.067,0.6057
5,1970,9.4059,1412,7960.9,0.0891,40.692,0.1567,41.53,0.7542
14,1970,0.7606,65,8971.89,0.2802,41.243,0.1282,28.539,0.5916
15,1970,2.2587,295,8218.4,0.1772,71.94,0.1623,39.2,0.6606
16,1970,1.3422,183,5063.49,0.096,74.43,0.2629,35.51,0.6411
17,1970,0.6159,50,9204.24,0.2963,90.47,0.0981,32.07,0.6056
20,1970,0.4887,14,5438.89,0.2994,86.11,0.4571,34.15,0.2435
22,1970,1.1474,90,7189.67,0.2855,79.101,0.2073,21.503,0.5072
25,1970,7.5492,2969,8183.34,0.2397,80.657,0.3972,9,0.3631
27,1970,2.0532,374,7884.94,0.2054,82.485,0.1208,26.3014,0.6737
28,1970,0.6363,67,6696.5,0.2447,58.258,0.3674,25.4,0.3879
30,1970,3.1504,378,7895.43,0.098,60.277,0.1996,42.4683,0.7024
31,1970,10.3136,1886,6833.93,0.0826,67.68,0.407,25.6,0.5104
32,1970,5.8488,1025,7093.32,0.2164,68.227,0.2455,22.2793,0.5382
35,1970,4.505,467,8410.34,0.2474,76.3,0.1917,26.85,0.561
36,1970,5.5971,938,7703.26,0.1577,77.197,0.2342,25.4,0.608
38,1970,3.7255,643,7332.13,0.2666,64.506,0.2428,21.1619,0.4905
41,1970,6.0065,1328,6680.77,0.1082,51.817,0.2611,25.2319,0.6307
44,1970,12.783,2632,8469.84,0.08,70.295,0.2604,30.971,0.6596
45,1970,6.6214,856,8033.72,0.1463,67.68,0.2083,39.5812,0.6554
46,1970,9.6429,2689,6364.4,0.0829,78.44,0.2105,23.4889,0.7067
47,1970,8.6852,1627,7912.4,0.1105,79.22,0.2071,31.6801,0.6824
48,1970,8.6372,1090,8507.92,0.2399,39.127,0.1796,33.9,0.5805
50,1970,11.2419,2258,6892.61,0.0997,81.096,0.2309,29.1,0.6694
55,1970,6.6221,1500,7588.7,0.1221,82.84,0.3186,21.3951,0.5594
57,1970,10.9665,2506,7412.36,0.1164,57.24,0.2152,27.4207,0.6684
58,1970,13.627,2437,7846.06,0.121,65.565,0.2578,30.6712,0.6212
59,1970,7.4395,1293,6821.09,0.2031,78.225,0.3297,21.4305,0.4672
61,1970,9.7843,1627,8355.75,0.1494,76.14,0.236,31.3374,0.6146
```

But when running the nls command, the error message comes up:

```
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In log(delta * K^(-rho) + (1 - delta) * L^(-rho)) : NaNs produced
```

But I don't know what value is missing.
Is it because the wrong choice of starting parameter values? If so, is there any good method to choose for this model?